Why is amazon.aws.s3_object throwing an error as ParameterValidation for the bucket name?
I have the following task:
amazon.aws.s3_object:
  bucket: <bucket-name>
  mode: list

But I am getting an error as:
task path: /runner/project/test-playbook.yml:32
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: S3ObjectFailure: Failed while looking up bucket 'bucket-name' (during bucket_check).
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py\\", line 196, in _new_conn\\n    sock = connection.create_connection(\\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py\\", line 60, in create_connection\\n    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):\\n               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/lib64/python3.11/socket.py\\", line 962, in getaddrinfo\\n    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):\\n               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\nsocket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known\\n\\nThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\\n\\nTraceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py\\", line 464, in send\\n    urllib_response = conn.urlopen(\\n                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py\\", line 843, in urlopen\\n    retries = retries.increment(\\n              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py\\", line 449, in increment\\n    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)\\n          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/util.py\\", line 39, in reraise\\n    raise value\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py\\", line 789, in urlopen\\n    response = self._make_request(\\n               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py\\", line 490, in _make_request\\n    raise new_e\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py\\", line 466, in _make_request\\n    self._validate_conn(conn)\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py\\", line 1095, in _validate_conn\\n    conn.connect()\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py\\", line 615, in connect\\n    self.sock = sock = self._new_conn()\\n                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py\\", line 203, in _new_conn\\n    raise NameResolutionError(self.host, self, e) from e\\nurllib3.exceptions.NameResolutionError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f385db82210>: Failed to resolve 'bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)\\n\\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\\n\\nTraceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload_gecqx9ai/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/s3_object.py\\", line 547, in bucket_check\\n  File \\"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload_gecqx9ai/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/module_utils/retries.py\\", line 105, in deciding_wrapper\\n  File \\"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload_gecqx9ai/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/module_utils/cloud.py\\", line 119, in _retry_wrapper\\n  File \\"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload_gecqx9ai/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/module_utils/cloud.py\\", line 68, in _retry_func\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py\\", line 569, in _api_call\\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py\\", line 1005, in _make_api_call\\n    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(\\n                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py\\", line 1029, in _make_request\\n    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)\\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\\", line 119, in make_request\\n    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)\\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\\", line 200, in _send_request\\n    while self._needs_retry(\\n          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\\", line 352, in _needs_retry\\n    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(\\n                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py\\", line 412, in emit\\n    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)\\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py\\", line 256, in emit\\n    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)\\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py\\", line 239, in _emit\\n    response = handler(**kwargs)\\n               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py\\", line 207, in __call__\\n    if self._checker(**checker_kwargs):\\n       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py\\", line 284, in __call__\\n    should_retry = self._should_retry(\\n                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py\\", line 320, in _should_retry\\n    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)\\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py\\", line 363, in __call__\\n    checker_response = checker(\\n                       ^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py\\", line 247, in __call__\\n    return self._check_caught_exception(\\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py\\", line 416, in _check_caught_exception\\n    raise caught_exception\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\\", line 279, in _do_get_response\\n    http_response = self._send(request)\\n                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py\\", line 375, in _send\\n    return self.http_session.send(request)\\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py\\", line 493, in send\\n    raise EndpointConnectionError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)\\nbotocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: \\"https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/\\"\\n\\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\\n\\nTraceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\"/runner/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1724637861.5301228-82-159619692773067/AnsiballZ_s3_object.py\\", line 107, in <module>\\n    _ansiballz_main()\\n  File \\"/runner/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1724637861.5301228-82-159619692773067/AnsiballZ_s3_object.py\\", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\\n  File \\"/runner/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1724637861.5301228-82-159619692773067/AnsiballZ_s3_object.py\\", line 47, in invoke_module\\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.amazon.aws.plugins.modules.s3_object', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible_collections.amazon.aws.plugins.modules.s3_object', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\\n  File \\"<frozen runpy>\\", line 226, in run_module\\n  File \\"<frozen runpy>\\", line 98, in _run_module_code\\n  File \\"<frozen runpy>\\", line 88, in _run_code\\n  File \\"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload_gecqx9ai/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/s3_object.py\\", line 1597, in <module>\\n  File \\"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload_gecqx9ai/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/s3_object.py\\", line 1570, in main\\n  File \\"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload_gecqx9ai/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/s3_object.py\\", line 1438, in validate_bucket\\n  File \\"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload_gecqx9ai/ansible_amazon.aws.s3_object_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/s3_object.py\\", line 569, in bucket_check\\nS3ObjectFailure: Failed while looking up bucket 'bucket-name' (during bucket_check).\\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

But when I try the same setting with other amazon.aws modules, the same setup works fine.
I tried amazon.aws.s3_bucket_info and amazon.aws.aws_caller_info. They are working correctly.
But this one particular module is not working fine.
Can anyone guide me through this?

Maybe it's an invalid bucket name? No underlines or spaces allowed. Only characters permissible in domain names are permitted.

I checked the bucket name, it is named correctly. It is working when I try it with other modules in amazon.aws.
It is just this particular module that is not working on AWX. The same task is working correctly on my local machine.
